# Adding a line to a file using sed in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ksh

I have a file which has 109 lines.

I perform the two operations on the line shown below.

```
# Delete line 74
sed -i '74d' Test.txt

# Add the entry to line 109
  sed -i "109iThis is the string" Test.txt
```

I see line 74 getting deleted from my Test.txt, but for some reasons, now my Test.txt has only 108 lines, and I don’t see the `This is the string` being added to line 109.

I am not sure what the error is. How can I fix it?

Comment: So you deleted a line from the file, in place, and now it has one less line. I don't see the problem. Change that second `sed` to hit line `108`.

Comment: Note that specifying the string after the `i` is a GNU-`sed`ism and not POSIX standard.  You should have a backslash-newline and then the string.  If you want the new line after the last line, use `$` to select the line number.  You could do both operations in a single command with `sed -i -e '74d' -e '$aThis is the string' Test.txt`.  (Also, the use of `-i` with no suffix is another GNU-`sed`ism.  Using `-i` works on BSD (macOS) room but only if you specify a backup suffix — `-i.bak` works with both.) Note that using `-i` before you know your scripts work is dangerous — it risks losing files.

Comment: @JNevill For some reasons, when I use 108, it adds it at 108 but moves the 108 entry to line 109. It still doesnt work

Comment: So you want to append after the last line, not insert before it — `i` is insert (before); `a` is append (after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan already mentioned the potential issues with using `sed -i` (non-standard, behaves in different ways when supported depending on implementation, etc.).  Avoid them by using `ed` to edit files:

```
ed -s Test.txt <<EOF
109a
This is the string
.
74d
w
EOF
```

Note how this appends, and then deletes. Because `ed` acts on entire files, not a stream of lines, commands to act on specific lines can be in any order.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this POSIX `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak '74d; $ a\
This is the string
' file
```

This will delete 74th line from file and append a line in the end and will save changes inline.

Note that this will work with `gnu-sed` as well.

Comment: `-i` isn't POSIX, btw

Answer (score 1):

If you remove a line, the file has only 108 lines left. Correct your second command accordingly:

```
sed -i "108iThis is the string" Test.txt
```

Comment: When I use this, it moves the entry at line 108 and adds my entry at 108. But I want dont want the entry at line 108 to move to line 109.

Comment: Okay switch from `108i` (insert) to `108a` (append).

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Your file has only 108 lines left and this way you add the desired line after line 108.

Answer (score 0):

Line number 109 does not exist (you removed one, 109-1=108), you must add it before you can enter text into it.

Solution:
`sed -i '$ a <text>' Test.txt`
The new line will be added with the selected text.

Comment: Can you reword this?  I'm not sure what you mean by `A little different ...`

Comment: Is this more understandable now?